# Unity ads displaying an ad example and not the real ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, unityads

http://prntscr.com/cv3hc3 and http://prntscr.com/cv3hh0 seems to be perfectly set up, while my ads still display the "unity ads" example. How can I display real ads and get money from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning test mode in the UnityAds dashboard on and back off again did it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set test mode to false? this is from the Unity blog:

> If we are running our project in the
>   editor we will see a generic billboard ad. If we are running this on
>   device and test mode is set to true (see above) then we will see a
>   placeholder ad. Finally, if we are on device and test mode is false we
>   will see a real live ad.

source: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/04/09/integrating-unity-ads/

I am not sure if your build target is properly set up, but this is a point worth mentioning as well:

> NOTE: Since ads are currently only supported for iOS and Android, your
>   editor will have to be targeting one of those platforms in order to
>   see any test ads. Before going further you may want to switch your
>   platform to either iOS or Android in the Unity build settings
>   (File->Build Settings)

source https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/04/09/integrating-unity-ads/

Comment: Test mode is turned off, as you can see in my screenshot. For the build, I'm currently using this: http://prntscr.com/cvggvq . Still can't figure out why it's not working...

Comment: did you go through the entire guide here from start to finish? https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/04/09/integrating-unity-ads/

Also did you go to Window->Services in Unity and set that up with your project ID ?

Comment: Just found a fix for it!

Answer (score 0):

just uncheck the TestMode in services then try to build the app and install it in real devices then it works great.